# Which type should I specify an image to be when using waterline?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Waterline in Sails is pretty cool and that layer of abstraction is very useful. My question is: how to store images using waterline? There is a type called binary. Should I use that type? Should I just trea image as any other data type? How to validate an image, say making sure its format is among a few given options, like png, jpeg etc.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't recommend using binary to store images directly in your db. If your users want to upload images, it's kind of a pain and I don't think waterline supports streaming to the database. There is an alternative though!

Mongodb has a feature called [gridfs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) which splits large files into chunks and stores them for you.

Sails's file upload library, [skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper), has the concept of adapters(like waterline) which allows you to plug an adapter into the file upload process. There's an adapter called [skipper-gridfs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/skipper-gridfs) which does this for you! I've used this and it's extremely easy to use. What you do is:

define a sails model, lets call it Image, it has the properties filename and filedescriptor

filedescriptor is the ID that mongo uses to reference the chunks.Basically, you're gonna store your file(any type of file) in gridfs and receive a filedescriptor. You're gonna save that in a model(Image model) and use that Model to download the file from gridfs later.

Here's some upload code:

```
var adapter = require('skipper-gridfs');


 upload : function (req, res, next) {

    var params = req.params.all();

    var gf = _gridfs;

    //upload file to gridfs
    req.file('file').upload(
        {
            adapter:adapter,
            uri:constring
        },
        function (err,uploadedFiles){
            if (err) {return res.send(err);}

            var imagePromiseArray = [];
            //loop over the files uploaded to gridfs and store references to their IDs   in your Image model
            _.each(uploadedFiles,function(file){
                var imageParams = {
                    filename:file.filename,
                    fileDescriptor:file.fd
                };
                imagePromiseArray.push(Image.create(imageParams));

            });

            Promise
                .all(imagePromiseArray)
                .then(function(results){
                    res.status(200);
                    return res.send(results);
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    res.status(500);
                    res.send(err);
                });

    });


},
```

and here's some download code:

```
var mime = require('mime');
download: function (req, res, next) {
    var params = req.params.all();

        Image
            .findOne(params.id)
            .then(function (image) {
                debugger;

                _gridfs.read(image.fileDescriptor, function (err, data) {

                    if (err) {
                        res.status(500);
                        res.json(err);
                    }
                    if (!data) {
                        res.status(404);
                        res.json({error: 'image not found'});
                    } else {
                        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + image.filename);
                        var type = mime.lookup(image.filename);
                        res.setHeader('Content-type', type);
                        res.send(data);
                    }
                });

            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                res.json(err);
            });


},
```

Comment: My problem here is that you basically said don't do whatever you are doing but do this in Mongo. If OP or any other isn't using mongo, we are left worse than empty handed. It is a great tip I assume, but not an answer.